# Hibernate Criteria API equivalent to HQL select clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

I'd like to have a combined query for two persistent classes.

In HQL this could be achieved by the select clause,

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
    from DomesticCat as mother
        join mother.mate as mate
        left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

In the above example, Family is a conbined class with DemesticCat as its construtor params

What is the Criteria equivalent of the HQL select clause ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a [`ResultTransformer`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) for this. The [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://relation.to/2133.lace) blog post gives the following example (where `StudentDTO` is a non-entity Bean):

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Enrolment.class)
  .createAlias("student", "st").createAlias("course", "co")
  .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                   .add( Projections.property("st.name"), "studentName" )
                   .add( Projections.property("co.description"), "courseDescription" )
          )
          .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class) )
          .list();

 StudentDTO dto = (StudentDTO)resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what i was looking for!
Seems Criteria is almost as powerful as HQL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Criteria API, this functionality is handled by [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection). The documentation is a bit confusing and over-complicated, but that's what you need to look at.

Comment: skaffman:

  thanks for your quick answer.
  I just briefed the Projections part, and found that
    PropProjection.Property.forName("name")   
  could be used to filter a subset of columns as the result,

  But i couldn't find a Projection that maps two Persistance classes into a new class, like the Family class in the above example ?

  Could you shed some light on that ?