# Hibernate Criteria equivalent to HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

Is there any hibernate criteria query exist equivalent to the following HQL?

"SELECT new TestTable(t.id,t.param1,t.param2,t.param3) FROM TestTable t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you want to load some columns of a table you may need `Projection`

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(TestTable.class, "t");
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("param1"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("param2"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("param1"));
crit.setProjection(projectionList);
List results = crit.list();
```

Comment: :Acutally my question was about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801764/hibernate-criteria-api-equivalent-to-hql-select-clause) and I got the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801764/hibernate-criteria-api-equivalent-to-hql-select-clause) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958222/using-hibernate-criteria-to-select-into-value-objects). Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is query the rows of TestTable and get TestTable hibernate objects, just create a Criteria object on the class of the Hibernate object you are trying to retrieve.

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(TestTable.class);
List results = crit.list();
```

Comment: Acutally my question was about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801764/hibernate-criteria-api-equivalent-to-hql-select-clause) and I got the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801764/hibernate-criteria-api-equivalent-to-hql-select-clause) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958222/using-hibernate-criteria-to-select-into-value-objects). Thanks for commenting.